# Is the Kosovan-Serbian border between Mitrovica and Novi Pazar open?

Tags: borders, serbia, kosovo

Looking at Google Maps, it would appear that there is no border control on the road between Mitrovica (Kosovo) and Novi Pazar (Serbia). [**Link**](https://www.google.ch/maps/@43.0493955,20.666768,1134m/data=!3m1!1e3)

Is this the case?

Comment: With the Kosovan side of the border being in the Serb controlled North Kosovo region, I would expect that you can and may cross the border here at any point, provided that you are already considered being legally present in Serbia. Hopefully someone with more knowledge about the current situation can give you better advice.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Jarinje is also in the north, and there's definitely border control there (including when I took the Mitrovica-Kraljevo train, where I was the only foreigner - Kosovan police boarded the train at Jarinje, and Serbian police at Rudnica)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google satellite shot has been updated, and a checkpoint can now be seen at the location.

What was the situation before? WHo knows? But there definitely is a checkpoint nowadays.